# jquery: follow up html with function?

Tags: jquery, function

I know this doesn't work:

$('#section').html($(data), function()
                    {
                        $('#section').fadeIn();
                    });

How would I go on writing it? It should be simply, but I've been away from jQuery for too long.
Thanks!

Comment: Could you please put what you are trying to achieve in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to call fadeIn after the html method is completed? You can simply do this,

```
$('#section')
    .html($(data))
    .fadeIn();
```

Above works because unlike the 'animate' methods, html method is synchronous. fadeIn method will be called only after html method has finished executing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `section` to fade in after you set its `innerHTML`, this is what you need:

```
$('#section').html($(data)).fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about using the document ready function to fade something once it's ready?

Anything you would need to know is right in their [Documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page). Since you didn't really ask a specific question, and you said you're familiar with it, it won't take much to figure out what you want to do.